# My code for solving a maze goes into an infinite loop

Tags: c, stack, maze

Currently, I have a maze solving algorithm, and it goes into inifinite loop for some reason, I have been on it for hours, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Am I doing something wrong. I am going to post some of the other necessary functions that "could" be the poential problem along with my maze solving code.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mazegen.h"
#define  MAXSIZE 100

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    char*readFile;
    char maze[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
    int rows=0;
    int cols=0;
    int x;
    int y;
    FILE*fp;
    int counter;
    int length=0;
    counter = 0;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
       printf("Cannot open file\n");
       exit(0);
    }

    readFile = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXSIZE);  

    while(fgets(readFile,MAXSIZE,fp) != NULL)
    {
        for(cols=0; cols <MAXSIZE; cols++) 
        {
            maze[rows][cols] = readFile[cols];
        }
        rows++;

        counter++;   
    }

    fclose(fp);

    length = strlen(readFile);

    mazeSolution(maze,counter, length); 

    for(x=0; x<rows; x++)
    {
       for(y=0; y<cols; y++)
       {
            printf("%c", maze[x][y]);
       }
    }



   free(readFile);

   return 0;
}
```

mazeSolve.c

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define  BUFFERSIZE 500
#define  FLAG 

void mazeSolution(char maze[100][100], int counter, int counter2)
{
   stack*currentCell;

   int i;
   int j;

   currentCell = create();


   /*push(currentCell, 1,2);
   push(currentCell, 3,4);
   pop(currentCell);
   printStack(currentCell);*/

   for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
   {
       for(j=0; j<counter2; j++)
       {
           if(maze[i][j] == 'S')
           {
               push(currentCell,i,j);
               i = counter;
               break;
          }   
      }
   }



   while(currentCell != NULL)
   { 
      if(maze[i][j] == 'F')
      {
           break;
      }

      if (maze[i][j] == ' ') 
      {
          maze[i][j] = '.';
      }

      if (i>0 && maze[i-1][j] == ' ') 
      {
          push(currentCell,i-1, j);
          i--;
      } 
      else if (j>0 && maze[i][j-1] == ' ') 
      {
          push(currentCell,i, j-1);
          j--;
      } 
      else if (i+1<counter && maze[i+1][j] == ' ') 
      {
          push(currentCell,i+1, j);
          i++;
       } 
       else if (j+1<counter2 && maze[i][j+1] == ' ') 
       {
          push(currentCell,i, j+1);
          j++;
       } 
       else 
       {
          pop(currentCell);
       }
   }

   if (listLength(currentCell->list) > 0)
   {
       printStack(currentCell);
   }
    else
    {
        printf("NO SOLUTION\n");
    }

}
```

stack.c

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

stack*create()
{
    stack*myStack;

    myStack = malloc(sizeof(stack)+1);

    myStack->list = createList();

    return myStack;
}

node*push(stack*theStack, int xpos, int ypos)
{
   node*top;

   if(theStack == NULL)
   {
       printf("Empty Stack.Error\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   top = addFront(theStack->list, xpos, ypos);

   return top;
}

void pop (stack*theStack)
{
    node*theHead;

    if(theStack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Stack. Error\n");
         exit(0);
    }

    theHead = removeFromFront(theStack->list);

    theStack->list = theHead;


}

void peek (stack*theStack)
{
    getFromFront(theStack->list);
}


void printStack(stack*theStack)
{
    if(theStack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Empty Stack. Cannot print stack\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    printList(theStack->list);

}
void destroyStack(stack*theStack)
{
    destroyList(theStack->list);

    free(theStack);

}
linkedList.c

#include "linkedList.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


node*createList()
{
    node*dummyNode; 

    dummyNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    dummyNode->next = NULL;

    return dummyNode; 
}

node*addFront(node*list, int xpos, int ypos)
{
   node*newNode;

   if(list == NULL)
   {
       printf("Add to front Error\n");
       exit(0);
   }

   newNode = initNode(xpos, ypos);

   newNode->next = list->next;

   list->next = newNode;

   return list;
}

void printList(node*theList)
{
    node*currentPosition;

    currentPosition = theList->next;

    while(currentPosition != NULL)
    {
        printf("This is the value of the current node : %d,%d\n",currentPosition->xpos, currentPosition->ypos);

        currentPosition= currentPosition->next;
    }

}

node*initNode(int xpos, int ypos)
{
    node*newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode->xpos = xpos;

    newNode->ypos = ypos;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;

}

void destroyList(node*theList)
{
    node*temp;

    while(theList->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = theList->next;
        free(theList);
        theList=temp;
    }
}

node*removeFromFront(node*theList) 
{
    node*temp;

    if (theList == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    temp = theList->next;
    theList->next = NULL;

    return temp;
}

int listLength(node*list)
{
    int length;
    node*ptr;
    length = 0;

    ptr = list->next;

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        length++;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }


    printf("This is the length of the list : %d\n",length);

    return length;
}

void getFromFront(node*theList)
{  
    node*temp;

    int value1;

    int value2;

    temp = theList->next;

     if(temp == NULL)
     {
         printf("Empty List.\n");
         exit(0);

     }

    value1 = theList->next->xpos;

    value2 = theList->next->ypos;

    printf("This is the value from the front : %d,%d\n", value1, value2);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it may be several things: your while loops. Your while loops use the expression

```
while (<insert code> != null)
{
<insert body of code>
}
```

using the `!= null` expression is tricky at times because unless the condition is true, it will continue going in an infinite loop. I noticed that in your code, you don't have any kind of exit statement in your while loops. In my experience while loops are the main causes of infinite loops. It doesn't seem that the condition will ever be false (`= null`). For example:

```
while(fgets(readFile,MAXSIZE,fp) != NULL)
{
    for(cols=0; cols <MAXSIZE; cols++) 
    {
        maze[rows][cols] = readFile[cols];
    }
    rows++;

    counter++;   
}
```

if the `fgets` method does not become null, you will never exit the while loop. You did not post the `fgets` method and so I'm afraid I can't say whether or not that's where your problem is located. The same concept is true for your second while loop.

A good strategy I often like to use when debugging infinite loops is having a `System.out.println` (I'm used to java haha), inside the while loop. Doing so allows me to see what the computer is doing inside the while loop.

Comment: Oh okay and I have never done java actually is system.out.println a printf statment within the while loop?? and I did post the fgets method did I not ? :S What do you suggest would be a good exit condition when dealing with while loops? one way would be to read till the end of file I guess instead of NULL

Comment: `System.out.println` is just printing out on the screen and yes, it would be inside your while loop. I'm sorry if I missed your fgets method, your code is on the longer side and I'm used to reading code in eclipse or BlueJ format, not SO's. As for while loops, generally honestly I try and avoid them. Instead of having something vague such as `!= null` try setting more specific conditions. This is why I find for loops to be a better option, they are more specific and don't tend to head into infinite loops as easily.

Comment: Well I tried something specific like while its not equal to an 'F' because that is the ending the position in our maze, however it does not seem to be work I might have to try putting a bunch of printf statements in the while loop like you said. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.